# Load Json response to combo box

Tags: jquery, json

I have a String array containing some names. I return it as a `Json` response and now I need to load those names in to a combo box in my `html` page. This is the function I wrote.

```
function loadSiteOfficers(ele){

    var selected = ele.value;
    if(selected == "Site Officer"){

        jQuery.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "/TFProject/load_officers.htm",

            success : function(response) {

                if (response.status == "SUCCESS") {

                    alert(response.result);
                } else {
                    ////// some code here 
                }
            },
            error : function(e) {
                alert('Error: ' + e);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

`alert(response.result)` gives me names separated by commas. They are retrieved from the database.
I am bit confused here and need to know how to load the data. I will be grateful if you can help me
Thanks.

Comment: Could you possibly add what the JSON looks like?

Comment: @natzim it contains string values separated by commas. ex:- when I try alerting them it alerted ABC,DEF . Those two vales are taken from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works

```
var selectDropDown = $('<select/>');
response.each(function(){
selectDropDown.append('<option>'+this+'</option>');
});
$('#divId').html(selectDropDown);
selectDropDown.combobox();
```

Thanks

Comment: I cannot understand the last two lines of this code snippet.Could you please explain them

Comment: $('#divId').html(selectDropDown); added the select dropdown to the div with id "divId"
selectDropDown.combobox(); created the combobox from select

Comment: I have already created the drop down combo box. So I think that code line is not needed? isn't it?

Comment: no, if you have already created the combobox then you need to destroy it and recreate it again.